# How to connect to BLE device with high security mode using bluetoothctl?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to **connect to a remote BLE device using the [security level Mode 1 Level 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963836/bluetooth-low-energy-gatt-security-levels)**. How do I do that using `bluetoothctl`, please?

I did:

1. **Connect** to the device (success)
2. **Pair** the device (success)

But, apparently, **this did not set the security mode as I wished** because when I try to write a given characteristic (this characteristic is writeable ;) I get the **ATT error "Insufficient authentication (5)"**

```
> ACL data: handle 70 flags 0x02 dlen 9
    ATT: Error (0x01)
      Error: Insufficient authentication (5)
      Write req (0x12) on handle 0x0014
```

Step by step, this is what `hcidump` shows after connect:

```
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7
    type 0x00 (passive)
    interval 60.000ms window 30.000ms
    own address: 0x00 (Public) policy: white list only
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2
    value 0x01 (scanning enabled)
    filter duplicates 0x01 (enabled)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 43
    LE Advertising Report
      ADV_IND - Connectable undirected advertising (0)
      bdaddr D2:A7:4C:76:F3:E0 (Random)
      Flags: 0x06
      Unknown type 0x06 with 16 bytes data
      Unknown type 0xff with 8 bytes data
      RSSI: -75
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2
    value 0x00 (scanning disabled)
    filter duplicates 0x00 (disabled)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25
    bdaddr D2:A7:4C:76:F3:E0 type 1
    interval 96 window 96 initiator_filter 0
    own_bdaddr_type 0 min_interval 6 max_interval 12
    latency 0 supervision_to 400 min_ce 0 max_ce 0
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19
    LE Connection Complete
      status 0x00 handle 70, role master
      bdaddr D2:A7:4C:76:F3:E0 (Random)
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12
    LE Read Remote Used Features Complete
      status 0x00 handle 70
      Features: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
< ACL data: handle 70 flags 0x00 dlen 7
    ATT: MTU req (0x02)
      client rx mtu 517
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
    handle 70 packets 1
...
```

Pairing does not actually show any more packets (!)

```
[D2A74C76F3E0]# pair D2:A7:4C:76:F3:E0
Attempting to pair with D2:A7:4C:76:F3:E0
[CHG] Device D2:A7:4C:76:F3:E0 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
```

Then, I do

```
[D2A74C76F3E0]# menu gatt
[D2A74C76F3E0]# select-attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D2_A7_4C_76_F3_E0/service000c/char0013
[D2A74C76F3E0:/service000c/char0013]# write 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
Attempting to write /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D2_A7_4C_76_F3_E0/service000c/char0013
```

and this issues the following packets:

```
< ACL data: handle 70 flags 0x00 dlen 8
    ATT: Write req (0x12)
      handle 0x0014 value  0xFF
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
    handle 70 packets 1
> ACL data: handle 70 flags 0x02 dlen 9
    ATT: Error (0x01)
      Error: Insufficient authentication (5)
      Write req (0x12) on handle 0x0014
(loop)
```

Note that it sends only one byte + it loops (*this is probably a bug*). But **what's important to me is the answer: "Error: Insufficient authentication (5)" which obviously means the security level is incorrectly set.**

If we look at information for the device:

```
# info
...
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
```

So, I believe I have connected but not with mode 1 level 3.
This is `bluetoothctl` **version 5.50** on a Linux Mint host.
Note that however **I get the same behaviour with `bluetoothctl` version 5.43 on a Raspberry Pi**, except that it sends correctly the entire write packet. But the answer is the same.

```
< ACL data: handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 15
    ATT: Write req (0x12)
      handle 0x0014 value  0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
> ACL data: handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9
    ATT: Error (0x01)
      Error: Insufficient authentication (5)
      Write req (0x12) on handle 0x0014
```