# Are GATT Event notifications possible without pairing?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt, btle

I've been pouring over the BT 4.x (LE) spec trying to figure out if this is possible or not (events without pairing/boding).

Does anyone have an insight (and link to the spec preferably) if it's possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In fact GATT does not require any pairing and/or bonding. Unfortunately I do not remember th exactly spec part where it is described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mike Petrichenko commented, GATT communication is definitely possible without pairing. In fact most GATT servers/clients out there function without the need for pairing/bonding. The only exception is when some characteristics require authentication/authorisation in order to read some data (e.g. a medical device with a Heart rate characteristic).

If you want a specific reference to where this is mentioned in the Bluetooth spec, then I recommend looking at the Core Specification version 5.2, Vol 3, Part C, section 10.2 (LE Security Modes):-

> The security requirements of a device, a service or a service request
> are expressed in terms of a security mode and security level. Each
> service or service request may have its own security requirement. The
> device may also have a security requirement. A physical connection
> between two devices shall operate in only one security mode.

It is then mentioned that **LE security mode 1** has the level **No security**, and many GATT servers/clients work in this level.

You can test this yourself if you have two phones available. You can use the nRF Connect app to run a [GATT server](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/65209/how-to-configure-gatt-server-in-nrf-app-to-test-cts-example) on one and a GATT client on the other. You will see that you can browse the GATT table and read data without having to pair.

Below are a few links that contain more information:-

- [Is pairing/encryption mandatory to allow a peer to write in GATT](https://community.cypress.com/t5/WICED-Smart-Bluetooth/Is-pairing-encryption-mandatory-to-allow-a-peer-to-write-in-GATT/td-p/110265)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy GATT security levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963836/bluetooth-low-energy-gatt-security-levels)
- [How GAP and GATT work](https://punchthrough.com/how-gap-and-gatt-work/)

Comment: Does that also include GATT Notifications (events)?  I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around that as wouldn't the GATT server on the device need to keep a "registered" list of "subscribers"?

Comment: Yes, it includes both Notifications (which do NOT require an acknowledgment back to the GATT Server) and Indications (which DO require acknowledgments). The way this works is by a device (GATT Client) connecting to another device (GATT Server), finding the Characteristic that supports Notifications, then performing a GATT Write operation to the Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor to enable Notifications. The GATT Server then will automatically send a Notification back to the GATT Client (if connected) when it wants to and/or when the Characteristic value changes.